# Can not get the data attribute

Tags: javascript, getattribute

I am trying to get the data attribute in my JavaScript. but it is coming undefined instead of true.

HTML code is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card" data-expand="true">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
            perferendis in temporibus reprehenderit. Vitae maxime, totam tempore
          </p>
          <button class="read">Read More</button>
          <button class="collaspe">Collaspe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card" data-expand="true">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
            perferendis in temporibus reprehenderit. Vitae maxime, totam tempore
          </p>
          <button class="read">Read More</button>
          <button class="collaspe">Collaspe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card" data-expand="true">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
            perferendis in temporibus reprehenderit. Vitae maxime, totam tempore
          </p>
          <button class="read">Read More</button>
          <button class="collaspe">Collaspe</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code is given below.

```
const readMore = document.querySelectorAll(".read");
const collapse = document.querySelectorAll(".collaspe");
const card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const para = card.forEach((el) => {
  el.getAttribute("data-expand");
});

readMore.forEach((read) => {
  read.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(para);
  });
});
```

Here I should have got "true" here. But why is it coming Undefined?

Comment: What do you think `forEach` returns? (And even if it was a `map`, what does your function for `card.forEach` return?

Comment: Apart from the fact that *para* is undefined because (as eluded to by @DaveNewton) *forEach()* returns undefined (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you also have the problem that you are trying to assign to *para* out of the context of the click event on *readMore* so you will not get the value of the *data-expand* attribute relevant to the *.read* button you clicked on.

Comment: I mean *alluded* not *eluded*!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** If you don't want to change your HTML I have added another solution after my preferred solution which is to change the HTML.

Is there some good reason why, in the HTML, you have to put the *data-expand* attribute in the *div* element? If you could put it in the same button that, when you click it, you have a click event handler fire, then you could easily get the value of *data-expand* from the event object available inside that event handler.

I have modified your HTML and JavaScript to show what I mean:

```js
const readMore = document.querySelectorAll(".read");

const collapse = document.querySelectorAll(".collaspe");

readMore.forEach((read) => {
  read.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  const para = event.target.dataset.expand;
    console.log(para);
  });
});
```

```html
        <div class="card">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
            perferendis in temporibus reprehenderit. Vitae maxime, totam tempore
          </p>
          <button class="read" data-expand="true">Read More</button>
          <button class="collaspe">Collaspe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
            perferendis in temporibus reprehenderit. Vitae maxime, totam tempore
          </p>
          <button class="read" data-expand="true">Read More</button>
          <button class="collaspe">Collaspe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
            perferendis in temporibus reprehenderit. Vitae maxime, totam tempore
          </p>
          <button class="read" data-expand="true">Read More</button>
          <button class="collaspe">Collaspe</button>
        </div>
```

Alternatively you can access the *data-expand* attribute's value from the event object in the HTML as you have it like this:

```js
const readMore = document.querySelectorAll(".read");
const collapse = document.querySelectorAll(".collaspe");

readMore.forEach((read) => {
  read.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  const para = event.target.parentElement.dataset.expand;
    console.log(para);
  });
});
```

```html
        <div class="card" data-expand="true">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
            perferendis in temporibus reprehenderit. Vitae maxime, totam tempore
          </p>
          <button class="read">Read More</button>
          <button class="collaspe">Collaspe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card" data-expand="true">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
            perferendis in temporibus reprehenderit. Vitae maxime, totam tempore
          </p>
          <button class="read">Read More</button>
          <button class="collaspe">Collaspe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="card" data-expand="true">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa
            perferendis in temporibus reprehenderit. Vitae maxime, totam tempore
          </p>
          <button class="read">Read More</button>
          <button class="collaspe">Collaspe</button>
        </div>
```